# boolean variables and small coding errors

Tags: c#, variables, boolean

Basically I am making a variable in the game where when a player passes a collider it displays the message shown. However, I have a few errors if someone could help me with. I'm not sure exactly where I went wrong and its gotten pretty frustrating.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class showMessage : MonoBehaviour {
    GameObject player;
    private bool  startLap;

    void  OnTriggerEnter ( Collider other  ){
        if(other.tag == "Player") {
            bool = true;
        }
    }

    void  OnGUI (){
        if(bool == true) {
            if(GUI.Button ( new Rect(100, 100, 500, 40), "Help! I lost my car. Find it through this maze for me?")) {
                Debug.Log("Door Works!");
                bool = false;

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Ok fixed the bool bool just saw that :\

The errors I am getting are:

> (10,30): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `=', expecting`.', `?',`[', `<operator>', or`identifier'
>
> (15,26): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `==', expecting`.'
>   error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `=', expecting`.'
>
> error CS8025: Parsing error

Comment: " I have a few errors " - and they are?

Comment: @MitchWheat posted those sorry!

Comment: @GrantWinney fixed! sorry i forgot that part

Comment: You must change "bool" to "startLap" not only in this field declaration line. You also must change name of this field where it's accessed(i.e lines 11, 16, and 23)

Answer (score 3):

**bool** is a reserved keyword for boolean value data type - don't use it as field name, or you will get many compilation errors. Rename this field to something else.

Your code must look like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class showMessage : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool startLap;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            startLap = true;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (startLap)
        {
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100, 100, 500, 40), "Help! I lost my car. Find it through this maze for me?"))
            {
                Debug.Log("Door Works!");
                startLap = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ..or use `@bool`... but probably a better idea to change it completely. The only place I've ever seen it widely adopted to use the keyword (with a `@` prefix) is in event-based architectures where `@event` is a common variable name.

Answer (score 2):

`private bool  startLap;`

This variable has the type `bool` and the name `startLap`.

Consider that you could have many such variables:

```
private bool startLap;
private bool foo;
private bool bar;
```

All of them have different names, but the same type `bool`.

Now in your code, you have

`bool = true;`

`if(bool == true) {`

`bool = false;`

Which variable are they referring to? From your example, I can guess since there's only one `bool` around, but since there *may* be others, you have to refer to all variables by name, not type:

`startLap= true;`

`if(startLap== true) {`

`startLap= false;`